# Example DataService (with EF) in SP2013

Tags: 2013, wcf, spcontext

Does anyone have a good example how to create a (WCF) dataservice in SharePoint 2013, WITH the use of Entity Framework?

I need to be able to retrieve the SPContext also, so I guess this will be a service in the ISAPI folder?